# Where clause applied to only one column in join

Tags: sql, left-join, where-clause

I'm having some trouble with writing a certain SQL query. I have a wallet and a balance which I do join. The query now looks like that:

```
SELECT
    `balances`.`id` AS `id`,
FROM
    `wallet` 
LEFT JOIN `balances` ON
    ( `wallet`.`currency` = `balances`.`currency` )
WHERE
    `balances`.`user_id` = '181'
```

Because of the `where` clause, the query returns just matching records. I want to get all records from wallets table and only those from balances which do match where clause... hope I explained it well enough!

Cheers!

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the end result to look like? At first glance it looks like this should be two separate queries.

Comment: Can you provide an example, clarifying what is the actual result and what do you expect instead?

Comment: you can use the SQL UNION Operator

Comment: Let's say there is like 100 wallet kinds, one wallet = one balance, certain user X have 5 balances so...  I want querry to return all those 100 wallets and matching balances from the balances table, but due to where clause querry returns just those 5 matching records...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use subquery

```
SELECT w.*,t.*        
FROM
    wallet w
LEFT JOIN ( select * from balances where user_id = 181
   ) t ON   w.currency =t.currency
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you are applying filter on left join table wallets.

use below query.

```
SELECT
    `balances`.`id` AS `id`,
FROM
    `wallet` 
LEFT JOIN (select * from `balances` `user_id` = '181') ON
    ( `wallet`.`currency` = `balances`.`currency` );
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not fully clear, but you almost definitely need an extra `join` clause on some sort of ID. Now there is no way to match a wallet with its balance(s). Assuming that balance have eg. a `wallet_id`, you'll want something like:

```
SELECT
    `balances`.`id` AS `id`,
FROM
    `wallet` 
LEFT JOIN `balances` ON
    (`wallet`.`id` = `balance`.`wallet_id` )
WHERE
    `balances`.`user_id` = '181'
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the condition to the `ON` clause.  Don't use subqueries!

```
SELECT w.*, b.id
FROM wallet w LEFT JOIN 
     balances b
     ON w.currency = b.currency AND
        b.user_id = 181;
```

Notes:

- The subquery in the `FROM` can impede the optimizer.
- If you are using a `LEFT JOIN`, you should be selecting columns from the *first* table.
- I am guessing that `user_id` is a number, so I removed the quotes around the comparison value.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Backticks make the query harder to write and harder to read.